# How to add a search bar and search display to an rss feed in a uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, rss

I created an RSS reader that parses from a .xml file. The **numberOfRowsInSection** and **cellForRowAtIndexPath** look like this:

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.parseResults.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //Check if cell is nil. If it is create a new instance of it
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure titleLabel
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.parseResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    //Configure detailTitleLabel
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.parseResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"summary"];

    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

    //Set accessoryType
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    //Set font and style
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];

    return cell;
}
```

I am trying to create a **search bar and search display controller**, but am not sure how to search the **objectForKey** "title" or **objectForKey** "summary" within the UITableView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to search for both title and summary, can you try this in your UISearchBarDelegate method

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
  if ([searchText length] == 0)
  {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    return;
  }

  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.title contains[cd] %@ OR SELF.summary contains[cd] %@", searchText, searchText];
  NSArray *filteredArray = [self.parseResults filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

  // TODO: Use this filteredArray to reload data

  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Sample project for your reference - https://github.com/deepthit/TableViewSearch.git

Comment: Hi. THANKS FOR YOUR HELP, IT'S GREATLY APPRECIATED. When I follow this the RSS feed does not load anymore in the tableview, so there are no results. Nevertheless when I try to search it does not correctly search the "title" or "summary" and the search results do not appear correctly -the cells are not neatly aligned after searching for something and getting results. Also, the search is not consistent - when running the app again, it does not display search results consistently. Note: I did follow the sample project you referenced above. THANKS FOR YOUR HELP IN ADVANCE.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work, however is there a way to change the size of the tableview cells while searching? What I mean is my tableview cells are larger than default because of the detailed text (summary) that shows up in the cells.  When I start searching the cells compact and cut some of my detailedtext out.